# How to Syncronize async data download with the main thread in swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, swift2

I have a problem. When my app start, it downloads async data from server in app Delegate, but it does a segue to the home screen. Then in the home screen, the app checks for this async data that have been downloaded in app delegate. If it doesn't find that data, then it loads offline content, because this data maybe is not ready yet or maybe the server is down and the app will never get this data.

My problem comes when effectively the app download that data but after the offline data has been loaded. I get a home screen loaded with offline data, but mixed with the new data.

In app delegate I've set the download async data in a core location delegate method, because this data will only be downloaded if the user grants location access to the app:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    if(hasBeenLaunched == false){
        hasBeenLaunched = true
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.loadCitySlugArray()

        }
    }
    //Other code...

}
```

I set `hasBeenLaunched` Bool to true when the app has entered to the download method, and then check for it in the home screen:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        if(hasBeenLaunched == false){
            //async data hasn't been downloaded from the server
            //load data to work offline or without location access
            let appDelgte = AppDelegate()
            appDelgte.loadOfflineSlug()
        }
        else//need to download home screen image
        {
            //Download Home Screen Image
            setHomeScreenImage()
        }

}
```

I've tried to put a sleep before the bool check, but it's no useful because the async data is not downloaded when sleep is active.

```
var seconds = 0
 repeat{
 sleep(1)
    seconds += 1
    if(seconds >= 5){break}
 }while hasBeenLaunched == false
```

Any one knows how to do that?

Comment: Try it by using ReactiveCocoa framework this may solve your problem.

Comment: there isn't a way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish in regular swift?

Comment: if that data is required for setting up the UI, then you shouldn't be downloading it async... you should download synchronously, check if you retrieved the data, and if not then use the offline content.... OR you can set up a notification for when the new data has been downloaded and reload the view once the new data is retrieved

Comment: the problem is I can't download it synchronously because it's in a core location delegate method and I can't control when this method is going to be called. Also, it can never be called, if the user don't grants location access.

Comment: - You should NOT do long running process on AppDelegate class .. load the app asap.  It looks like viewDidLoad method is called before async task is done. try move hasBeenLaunched condition to viewWillAppear .. set a breakPoint when at if condition and see the value.

Comment: @ChamiraFernando I'm not doing any long running in AppDelegate. As I said, the download is ASYNC so the app loads ASSAP

Comment: if app is loaded asap .. then viewDidLoad() method is executed before hasBeenLaunched is set to be true. thats where the problem is.

Comment: I already know were the problem is and if you take a second to read the post you'll know it too, but thanks for your conclusion. Yes effectively the home viewDidLoad method is launched before the delegate method of core location which is in App Delegate but ¿there is something I can do with this¿

Comment: okay.. Application architecture does not look good.. though

Comment: Then what is the good architecture in your opinion? Because stackoverflow is not to say "this is not good" but to provide a solution (if able to provide one...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118550/discussion-between-chamira-fernando-and-user3033437).

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog for the moment, the best suggested solution